# Count all lines between a delimiter

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I want to count the number of addresses attached to each device in the below example.  Preferably using awk or sed.

```
/dev/1
addr1 sometext sometext sometext
addr2 sometext sometext sometext
addr3 sometext sometext sometext
/dev/2
wwpn1 sometext sometext sometext
wwpn2 sometext sometext sometext
/dev/3
addr1 sometext sometext sometext
addr2 sometext sometext sometext
addr3 sometext sometext sometext
addr4 sometext sometext sometext
/dev/4
addr1 sometext sometext sometext
```

Below will give me a single match, but I am having trouble incrementing this for all devices outside of just running the command manually a bunch of times:

```
sed -n '/\/dev\/1/,/\/dev\/2/'p 
/dev/1 
addr1 sometext sometext sometext
addr2 sometext sometext sometext
addr3 sometext sometext sometext
/dev/2
```

What I am looking to do would iterate through all devices, so something like:

```
for i in `grep 'dev' somefile`; do sed -n '/$i/,/$insersecondmatchhere/'p ; done
```

The problem, is that I am not sure how to get the $insertsecondmatchhere variable from the for loop at the beginning of the command.

Comment: This question was flagged as "unclear what you're asking". Please edit your post and add an example of desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simplistic way in `awk`; if it sees the /dev/[0-9] pattern, it dumps any existing saved pattern & count, then resets the device & count; otherwise, it increments a counter. Once it reaches EOF, it dumps the saved pattern & count.

```
#!/bin/awk -f
{
  if ( /\/dev\/[0-9]/ ) {
    if (dev) { print dev, count; };
    dev=$0;
    count=0;
  } else {
    ++count;
  }
}
END {
  print dev, count;
}
```

and since you have several awk versions and terdon's perl solution, here's an ugly bash + grep + sed solution, since that seemed to be the direction you were going initially:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a devs
devs=( $(grep ^/dev/ input) )
for ((i=0; i < ${#devs[@]} - 1; i++)); do
  start=${devs[i]}
  end=${devs[i+1]}
  start=${start//\//\\\/}
  end=${end//\//\\\/}
  count=$(sed -n "/^$start/,/^$end/p" input | wc -l)
  count=$(( count - 2 ))
  echo for ${devs[i]}, count is $count
done
start=${devs[i]}
start=${start//\//\\\/}
count=$(sed -n "/^$start/,\$p" input | wc -l)
count=$(( count - 1 ))
echo for ${devs[i]}, count is $count
```

The main hack is escaping the forward-slashes in the device names before passing them to `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
awk -v RS="/dev/" 'NR!=1 {print "/dev/"$1":"NF-1}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` approach:

```
$ awk '{if(/^\//){n=$0;}else{l[n]++}}END{for(n in l){print n" : "l[n]}}' file 
/dev/1 : 3
/dev/2 : 2
/dev/3 : 4
/dev/4 : 1
```

The awk script will set `n` to the current line if the current line starts with a `/`. If it doesn't, it will increase the value of `l[n]`, i.e. the value stored in the associative array `l` for the current value of `n`. This is what will count the lines per section. Once the whole file has been read, in the `END{}` block, we print each `n` (section name, the `dev` lines) and the number of lines in that section.

You could golf that to:

```
awk '{/^\//?n=$0:l[n]++;}END{for(n in l){print n" : "l[n]}}' file
```

And the same idea in (golfed) Perl:

```
$ perl -lne'/^\//?$n=$_:$l{$n}++;}{print"$_ : $l{$_}"for keys(%l)' file 
/dev/2 : 2
/dev/1 : 3
/dev/3 : 4
/dev/4 : 1
```

Which can be expanded to:

```
perl -lne 'if(/^\//){$n=$_}
           else{ $l{$n}++ } 
           END{print"$_ : $l{$_}" for keys(%l)}' file
```